# Using map to get all but last in data array

Tags: jquery, arrays, dictionary

The following iterates over certain `<th>` elements and creates an array of the text, with each array entry surrounded by `<span>` tags.

But, I don't ever need the content of the last `<th>` element - is there a way to easily omit it from the function?

```
var newContent = $('#tableHead').find('th').map(function(){
    return '<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.slice(0, -1)`

```
var newContent = $('#tableHead').find('th').slice(0, -1).map(function(){
    return '<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
}).get();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/R6CPx/

Comment: I'm assuming this would also be slightly quicker than the `.not(":last")` way?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.not(":last")` to remove last `th` from list

```
var newContent = $('#tableHead').find('th').not(":last").map(function(){
    return '<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
}).get();
```

Comment: @verism `slice(0, -1)` incase if you want array methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ":not(:last-child)" selector. Try the following:

```
var newContent = $('#tableHead').find('th:not(:last-child)').map(function(){
    return '<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>';
}).get();
```